# What is the difference between "pescado" and "pescados?"

Tags: uso-de-palabras, plurales, sustantivos

In English, we make the distinction between "fish" and "fishes."  Does that same distinction exist between the Spanish words "**pescado**" and "**pescados**?"  If not, which of the following sounds more "natural":

"**Come pescado,**"

or

"**Come pescados,**"

or is it dependent on the situation (other than what exists in English)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Pescado* can be uncountable referring to a general foodstuff:

> Comí pescado hoy

But it can also be used as a countable referring to a single (caught) fish, in which case it can needs to be pluralized if more than one:

> Comí solo un pescado hoy.
>   ¿Te crees? ¡Comí diez pescados hoy!

In English, fish is invariable be it countable or uncountable. It only has a variable form in the plural to refer to types of fish (e.g. *bass and trout are freshwater fishes*). In Spanish, you would still use the plural form, or to emphasize the typification shown in  English, one could say *tipos/clases/especies de pescado*.

Comment: Excellent answer, guifa, and such a quick reply, too.  You are the best.